# How can I center text (constantly) in a responsive manner?

Tags: html, css, text, responsive, centering

I am pretty new to coding. I am learning HTML and CSS. I would like to know how I can make this title and subtitle centered in the four form factors (sizes I precized).

I am not sure why using white-spaceno wrap does not help :(

```css
 .text-block {
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        top: 10px;
        right: 50vh;
        left: 50vh;
        white-space:nowrap;
        
    
    }
    
    
    .thecloud {
      background: URL("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      width: 100vh;
    }
    
    .container{
     position: relative;
    }
    
    .title{
    
      font-family: 'Poppins';
    
    }
    
    .subtitle{
    
      font-family: 'Poppins';
    
    }
```

```html
   <div class="container">
          
          <picture>
            <img
              src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080"
            />
          </picture>
        </div>
    
        <span style="text-align:center" class="text-block">
    
          <h1 class="title">Hubble Space Telescope</h1>
    
          <h2 class="subtitle">30 Years of Discovery</h2>
    
        </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the centering of the text like this: (note: I changed your HTML a little bit.)

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
.text-block{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <picture>
      <img alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080"/>
    </picture>
    <span style="text-align:center" class="text-block">
        <h1 class="title">Hubble Space Telescope</h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle">30 Years of Discovery</h2>
    </span>
</div>
```